# How to show the message when the searchResult is empty

Tags: angular

Trying to display the message when the searchResult is empty. But not getting the desired result.
Here is my component and service file.

```js
Component.ts

    ngOnInit() {
    this.searchResult = this.service.searchResult$.subscribe(cars => {
      this.searching = false;
      this.rows = cars;
      if(cars.length === 0) {
        return [-1];
      }
      else {
        this.alertService.showInfoAlert('content not available');
      }
    });
    }
  
  service.ts
  
  showInfoAlert(msg: string) {
    this.showAlert(true, msg, 'alert-container');
  }
```

Comment: can you show the code of showAlert?

Comment: What's the current behavior of code, any errors etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.searchResult = this.service.searchResult$.subscribe(cars => {
        this.searching = false;
        this.rows = cars;
        if (!cars || cars.length === 0) {
            this.alertService.showInfoAlert('content not available');
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you this sample?

```
**Component.ts**

ngOnInit() {
this.searchResult = this.service.searchResult$.subscribe(cars => {

  if(jsonEmptyCheck(car)) {
    return [-1];
  }
  else {
    this.alertService.showInfoAlert('content not available');
  }
});
}
jsonEmptyCheck(jsonObject) {
            if (jsonObject != null) {
                if (Object.keys(jsonObject).length > 0) {
                    return  true;
                }
            }
            return  false;
        }
```